# How to efficiently pass the same "prop" to every stateless presentation component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have what looks like it will be a simple and common case of non-DRY code - I'm hoping there's a way to avoid this.

I have a page to render information about an object based on a route like this:

```
  <Route path="project/:projectid" component={ProjectDetails}/>
```

So... the 'project id' comes in as a prop from React Router, and every stateless presentation component needs the resulting project object:

```
class ProjectDetails = ({project}) => {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="project-details-page container-fluid">
             <HomeLeftBar/> 
             <div className="col-md-10">
                 <ProjectHeaderBar project={project}/>
             </div>
             <div className="project-centre-pane col-md-7">
                 <ProjectActions project={project}/>
                 <ProjectDescription project={project}/>
                 <ProjectVariations project={project}/>
             </div>
             <div className="project-right-bar col-md-3">
                 <ProjectContacts project={project}/>
                 <ProjectCosting project={project}/>
             </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default connect(
   state => ({project: state.projects[state.router.params.projectid]})
)(ProjectDetails)
```

How should I clean this up, so I don't have to pass the `project` to every component?

---

I've noted a couple of similar questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299031/pass-props-to-every-component) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083084/how-to-pass-a-prop-to-every-component-in-react-js) at least.  But while their titles are similar, their details are not.  They seem to ask more advanced questions about more specific situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, passing the data down from the top via props is the clearest way to get data into your leaf components, so I think what you've done here is fine.

The bit that looks not-clean is that you're passing the whole `project` object to every component but at a glance, it looks as though each of those components is responsible for rendering only a portion of that `project` object.

Passing only the branches of `project` that each component needs will make the relationship between the data and the view much clearer.

`<ProjectContacts project={project.contracts}/>
<ProjectCosting project={project.costing}/>`

and in turn I think this will make the whole component feel cleaner:

```
class ProjectDetails = ({project: { costings, description, variations, title, actions, contacts} }) => {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="project-details-page container-fluid">
             <HomeLeftBar/> 
             <div className="col-md-10">
                 <ProjectHeaderBar title={title}/>
             </div>
             <div className="project-centre-pane col-md-7">
                 <ProjectActions actions={actions}/>
                 <ProjectDescription description={description}/>
                 <ProjectVariations variations={variations}/>
             </div>
             <div className="project-right-bar col-md-3">
                 <ProjectContacts contacts={contacts}/>
                 <ProjectCosting costings={costings}/>
             </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right.  My construction was basically lazy-thinking about the presentation components' interface and role.

Comment: When the API for a thing isn't yet decided I usually go ahead and imagine my own perfect API. If the new API turns out to be different, maybe I'll change the way my thing works but often I'll reduce the API data into the shape I want it. APIs are often designed with certain goals in mind and its goals are often not the same goals as those of the display and that's ok. Usually I end up with data from many API end points being re-shaped before it goes into the store. Do what works best for you.

Comment: I've discovered the reason (good or bad) why I did it that way.  It's because I don't yet know the implementation of a 'project'.   I know that it will be rendered as per the composition component (because there is a mockup that says so), but for example I don't know whether a project has a field called 'variations', or whether this is something the presentation component will have to extract in a more complicated way....    (re-phrased my comment while Jamie was responding to it, ooops!)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using react-router. You can do something like this:

```
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="project/:projectId">
                <Route path="participants" component={Participants} />
                <Route path="progress" component={Progress}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
```

All children of `<Route path="project/:projectId">` have `this.props.params.projectId` available. For example, url to the Participants component is `"project/:projectId/participants"`, and therefore `projectId` is a param when rendering Participants.

Also, if the project details should be rendered the same way on all pages, you can add a component on the Route to "project/:projectId", which is responsible for doing rendering the project details. (That component would receive Participants or Progress as `this.props.children`, which you'd have to render in the new component.)

Comment: This seems to be a method for passing the same projectid prop to different pages.   Each of Participants and Progress appear to be pages on a different route - is that correct?    That doesn't match this situation.   I have one page related to projects, with one route.  That single page "ProjectDetails" is rendered by a composition of presentational components, such as Variations, Actions etc..

Comment: Good that it was useful, although I see that I had misunderstood your question. The accepted answer is a good way of composing components with React. If you do use react-router to solve it, I'd be interested to hear how (I'm not sure that would be the way to go to be honest :P).

Comment: I learned about composing  components via the route, but does turn out that it's not what I was looking for.